# angularjs: can't show the returned value of JS `typeof`

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a plnkr of a simple code that tries to display the value of `typeof("a")` in an html page. What I always get is nothing displayed, while I'm expecting for "string". The same goes for other data types. Here is my plnkr:
https://plnkr.co/edit/mUASA8s9TgplwysMhXvG?p=preview

Am I missing something?
I'll note that my final goal is to use `ng-if` with a condition that is based on the type of a variable.

Angular version: 1.4.8

Comment: it is searching for $scope.typeof . You have to define it via $scope.typeof = function(data) { return typeof data; };

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you not access directly typeof in TEmplate. other approach use this:

In Controller

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
  $scope.typeOfFun = function(name){
    return typeof name;
  }
});
```

In Templte

```
<div>{{typeOfFun("a")}}</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code has several problems:

1. [typeof](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof)'s syntax is `typeof a` and not `typeof(a)`
2. `typeof` is not a legitimate expression for angular's [expression-binding](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression), thus isn't printed to the template.

Considering the two points above, you should move the check to an external function and use the correct syntax - and everything works :)

See [the corrected code](https://plnkr.co/edit/Q7TxWnsZEbBB3tBWMAcV?p=preview):

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
  $scope.getTypeOfA = function() {
    return typeof "a"
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.8/angular.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <p>Hello {{name}}!</p>
    <div>{{"aaa"}}</div>
    <div>{{getTypeOfA()}}</div>
  </body>

</html>
```

**Obviously, you would want to pass a variable to the "checkTypeOf" function and return the result and not do it as I did. This is only for demonstration purposes!!!!**